# Understanding the auto-allocated disk layout on OpenBSD

Tags: mount, partition, disk, openbsd

I am attempting to install OpenBSD7.4 on an amd64 arch with a 1TB drive.

The machine will run an X windows system and need plently of room to store files.

I selected "whole disk GPT" at the prompt (though I'm unsure whether MBR might be the better option).

An auto-allocated layout is created:

12 partitions are created, `a` through `l`.

A summary:

```
partition    size (M)    fstype    mount point(I think)
a:           1024        4.2BSD    /     
b:           4129        swap       
c:           915715      unused      
d:           4096        4.2BSD    /tmp  
e:           11842       4.2BSD    /var
f:           30720       4.2BSD    /usr
g:           1024        4.2BSD    /usr/X11R6
h:           20480       4.2BSD    /usr/local  
i:           260         MSDOS    
j:           3072        4.2BSD    /usr/src  
k:           6144        4.2BSD    /usr/obj
l:           307200      4.2BSD    /home
```

`c` is ~915GB and is marked as unused. I'd like to adjust the layout to make use of it.

Decanting from the man pages I can see the following definitions:

| partition/mount point | Summary from [hier](https://man.openbsd.org/hier) |
| --- | --- |
| `/` | root |
| `/tmp` | Temporary files that are not preserved between system reboots. |
| `/var` | Multi-purpose log, temporary, transient, and spool files. |
| `/usr` | Contains the majority of user utilities and applications |
| `/usr/X11R6` | Files required for the X11 window system. |
| `/usr/local` | Local executables, libraries, etc. |
| `/usr/src` | BSD and/or local source files. |
| `/usr/obj` | Architecture specific target tree produced by building the /usr/src tree. |
| `/usr/home` | Default location for user home directories. |

However, I'm struggling to reason about this and have the following questions (with current best guess answers in italics):

**1. Why does the automatic layout pick the above mount points in particular?**
*Evolved generic allocation based on historical use and estimates.*

**2. Why is there an unused partition?**
*An artifact of the [automatic disk allocator](https://man.openbsd.org/disklabel#AUTOMATIC_DISK_ALLOCATION) which sets a maximum limit for the size of partitions - leftovers are unused.*

**3. Is is a good idea to put it all on a single partition instead?**
*No idea!*

**4. What might be a good practice allocation for a general use PC (with X windows) - where should I re-allocate the `c` partition?**
*I guess I should reallocate the unused `c` to `l`/`/usr/home` given that I may be saving a lot of files in userspace.*

---

*Perhaps there's an obvious man page I missed. Here's what I've seen:

https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#Partitioning

https://man.openbsd.org/disklabel#AUTOMATIC_DISK_ALLOCATION

https://man.openbsd.org/hier

https://www.openbsdhandbook.com/disk_operations/*

Comment: Could you please detail what remains unclear to you after reading the first paragraph of the faq you link to ?

Comment: @MC68020 will attempt to clarify the question...

Comment: `c` is the whole disk, always. Not really a partition that you will be able to mount. It will always be labelled as "unused".  This is described in the `disklabel` manual that you link to.

Comment: Your 3rd question is answered by the OpenBSD Handbook page that you link to.  The 4th question is a non-question once you have answered the other questions.

Comment: ... and your suggestion for an answer to the first question is probably more or less correct, which leaves me wondering whether you could possibly reformulate your post so that you ask about something that you have less of a clue about and _can't_ find in the documentation that you presumably have read?

Comment: @Kusalananda rtm is the short answer then, more or less. I'll see if I can re-formulate or might delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Why does the automatic layout pick the above mount points in particular?

This layout is suggested based on the experience of the developers and the needs of the system.
For example, the / partition contains the minimum required for the system to work, it works even in case of issue with other partitions. /tmp and /var are often written and so are more subject to problems. A problem on
these partitions must not prevent the system from booting.

As you mentioned, [hier(7)](https://man.openbsd.org/hier) describes the filesystem layout.

## 2. Why is there an unused partition?

Quoted from [disklabel(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/disklabel):

> disklabel supports 15 configurable partitions, ‘a’ through ‘p’, excluding
> 'c'.  The ‘c’ partition describes the entire physical disk, is
> automatically created by the kernel, and cannot be modified or deleted by
> disklabel.  By convention, the ‘a’ partition of the boot disk is the root
> partition, and the ‘b’ partition of the boot disk is the swap partition,
> but all other letters can be used in any order for any other partitions
> as desired.

The c partition is special, it represents the whole device, it's not an unused partition.

As a comparison: on Linux /dev/sdX represents the whole device, and /dev/sdX1 a partition on the device.
On OpenBSD, /dev/sdXc represents the whole device, and /dev/sdXa a partition
on the device.

## 3. Is is a good idea to put it all on a single partition instead?

You could use a different partitioning, depending on your needs. But using a
single partition is probably not a good idea.

1. If everything is on the same partition, any problem with the filesystem could prevent the system from booting. On the other hand, having at least a separate root partition allows the system to boot in single user mode in case of issue.
2. Some filesystems are mounted with different options, as you can see in the /etc/fstab file (see [mount(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/mount) and [fstab(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/fstab)). All partitions except / are mounted with option `nodev`. /tmp is also mounted with option `nosuid`, which is good for security reasons. With a single partition, you couldn't benefit from this.

## 4. What might be a good practice allocation for a general use PC (with X windows) - where should I re-allocate the c partition?

As explained above, you don't need to re-allocate the c partition since it
represents the whole device. Your ~915GB are shared this way:

~1GB to /, to contain /bin, /sbin, and maybe more.
~4GB to the swap.
~4GB to /tmp to contain temporary files.
~11GB to /var to contain logs, backups and more.
~30GB to /usr to contain user utilities and more.
~1GB to /usr/X11R6 to contain X window system's files.
~20GB to /usr/local/ to contain the programs and libraries installed by the user.
~260MB to the boot partition
~3GB to /usr/src/ to contain the source code of OpenBSD.
~6GB to /usr/obj/ to contain the results when building /usr/src.
~307GB to /home to contain your personal files and more.

From [disklabel(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/disklabel.8#AUTOMATIC_DISK_ALLOCATION) "AUTOMATIC DISK ALLOCATION" section, you can see
that in the automatic layout, the /home partition can be assigned up to 300GB.

```
             > 10GB Free      > 2.5GB         > 700MB        < 700MB
/           150MB –   1GB   800MB –   2GB   700MB –   4GB   1MB – 2GB
swap         80MB – 256MB    80MB – 256MB     1MB – 256MB   
/usr        1.5GB –  30GB   1.5GB –  30GB       
/home         1GB – 300GB   256MB –   2GB       
/tmp        120MB –   4GB           
/var         80MB –   4GB           
/usr/X11R6  384MB –   1GB           
/usr/local    1GB –  20GB           
/usr/src    1.5GB –   3GB           
/usr/obj      5GB –   6GB
```

If you want to use the unused ~528GB, you could increase the size of the /home partition or reinstall OpenBSD and manually adjust the disk layout.

Beside these ~528GB, there is enough place for the system to run on a desktop with graphical applications.
I recently installed OpenBSD 7.4 on a laptop, and started to take some notes about [running OpenBSD on desktop](https://www.openbsd-desktop.rocks/).